# What's wrong with the reputation counter?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Today I've encountered something strange happening to the reputation counter. Always, when someone upvotes my post (feel free to do so :-), the counter in the top bar shows that the value increased by that upvote plus an extra 15. When I refresh the page, it goes back to the correct (?) value.

Could you check what might be wrong, if possible? Have you been working on that counter these days?

This is the state when I've had 19,265 and someone upvoted my answer:

[image]

And this is the state when I refreshed the page:

[image]

This happens to me in Chrome and I've tried to clear logout, clean completely the whole history and restart the browser. Unfortunately, it remains the same.

If it's duplicate, let me know and I'll delete this question.

Comment: Decreases in reputation don't auto-update.

Comment: Ok, but [it's not happenstance](http://i.imgur.com/cdJL5.png) (look at the time). Check the time, it's 19:37 UTC, few minutes ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your rep got out of sync due to a deadlock earlier today.  While this would have fixed itself tonight (these do happen, though rare), I kicked the sync off early so you're all set now.